# Vuetify v-spacer is not working with v-tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to place logo on left side of navbar and tabs on the right side. I use `v-space` to do it but it doesn't work. I checked - it works fine with `v-btn` but not with `v-tabs`. I use Vue 2 and Vuetify 2.6:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>  
    <v-main>
      <Navbar />
      <router-view/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

**Navbar.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar 
    app
    dense
    dark >

        <v-img
          alt="Vuetify Logo"
          class="shrink mr-2"
          contain
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/vuetify-logo-dark.png"
          transition="scale-transition"
          width="40"
        />

    <v-spacer></v-spacer>   

    <v-tabs>
      <v-tab>Project</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Users</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Settings</v-tab>
    </v-tabs> 

  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

This is what I got:

[image]

I wanted menu (tabs) to be aligned to the right. Why `v-spacer` is not working here?
I also checked this topic https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/165 but it also does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70115344-jzhii?file=/src/components/Navbar.vue

There's no need to use a **v-spacer**. You only need to set the **right** prop to the v-tabs component.

```html
    <v-tabs right>
      <v-tab>Project</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Users</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Settings</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your example is taken from vuetify landing page. I also checked how it works there  and I can see that there's <v-spacer> put between logo and buttons. It works then. In your example it works only with 'right'. I'm curious why v-spacer doesn't work here?

Comment: Hi!, on vuetify default landing page they use a <v-spacer> because they are using a button instead tabs. The **<v-tabs>** component takes all the available horizontal space where it's located. That's why the <v-spacer> has no affect on it, but it has props like **centered** and **right** that let's you align the tabs acordingly.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Try `<v-tabs right>`

```html
<template>
  <v-app-bar 
    app
    dense
    dark >

        <v-img
          alt="Vuetify Logo"
          class="shrink mr-2"
          contain
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/vuetify-logo-dark.png"
          transition="scale-transition"
          width="40"
        />

    <v-tabs right>
      <v-tab>Project</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Users</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Settings</v-tab>
    </v-tabs> 

  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```